# что тестировать в представлении?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine

если кто-нибудь пользуется backbone + jasmine, то подскажите пожалуйста как можно протестировать такое простенькое представление:

```
APP.DepartCityView = Backbone.View.extend({   

  id: 'departCityWidget',

  template: _.template($('#departCityTpl').html()),

  render: function () {  
    this.$el.html(this.template());
    return this;
  } 

});
```

проблема в том, что я не понимаю что именно здесь можно протестировать. вот моя попытка:

```
describe("DepartCityView:", function() {
  beforeEach(function () {
    this.view = new APP.DepartCityView();
  });  

  it ('should init successful', function () {
    expect(this.view).toBeDefined();
  }); 

  it ("produces the correct HTML", function() {
    this.view.render();

    var id = this.view.$el.attr('id');
    expect(id).toEqual('departCityWidget');
  }); 
});
```

но даже здесь второй тест явно бесполезный. а хотелось бы протестировать в этом представлении вообще всё, что тестируется

вот шаблон:

```
<script type="text/template" id="departCityTpl">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h2>Город отправления</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="widget_content form-group col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fldDepartCity">
        <div id="errMsg_departCity" class="help-block"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Ответ немного не по теме. View это прослойка между DOM и бизнес логикой. Поэтому тестировать конкретно вью - мы отказались. Тестами облагаются коллекции, модели и бизнес логика. Для тестирования кликов, выборов мы используем selenium автотесты.